# How to divide the honors at a wedding?

Tags: minhag, wedding, social-convention

How are the kibudim at a typical Yeshivish American chasuna divided up between the choson's side and the kallah's side?

Comment: Is this a question about Jews, or Judaism? || Why is this tagged 'halacha'?

Comment: However the bride and groom want?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37036/759

Answer (score 1):

As one who has made a few weddings, the rule is that there are no rules. Generally the Mesader Kiddushin is the boy's Rosh HaYeshiva or a Rabbi that the boy is close to. Regarding the reading of the Kesuba, most common I have found is that the girl's side selects the one to receive that honor. Witnesses are usually split with one from each side. The Brachos are split, however I found that it is more common that the boy's side gets more than the girl's side.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly, *mesader kiddushin* is a rabbi that the groom trusts. (Though it has been proposed that theoretically, it should be whichever rabbi the majority of the crowd knows/trusts/prefers.) Beyond that, from what I've seen it's usually a fairly even split when possible. It's not uncommon for each side to pick one of the witnesses; and the sheva brachos are usually divided more or less evenly between the sides. (I'm not aware of any formula which bracha has to belong to whom, but if you listen to how they're called out, it's usually three-to-four people on his side, and three-to-four people on hers.)

I can't help but mention the (true) story of a chassidish fellow who married his second cousin. *Mechubad with third bracha, Rabbi Ploni BenPloni, great-uncle of the chosson. [Pause.] AND the kallalh!*