# Kibbudim at a Wedding

Tags: wedding, how-to, kavod

Can someone please provide a list of all the kibbudim  (honors) available at a Jewish wedding - from the beginning to end, in order?

Comment: Does signing tenaim count? I don't consider that a kibbud. I think of it more as a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Most consider being the groom to be the highest honor. He's really the center of attention.

Comment: Some context http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66604/must-the-first-and-second-bracha-of-sheva-brachos-be-said-together-by-one-person/67211#comment200103_66604

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37036/whats-the-order-of-importance-of-honorees-under-a-chuppa

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37036/whats-the-order-of-importance-of-honorees-under-a-chuppa?noredirect=1&lq=1 seems like a dup to me.

Comment: @MarkA. At the risk of being overly pedantic, divorcing the question from any issue of halakha, mahashava, history of Jewish practice, etc. Potentially reduces it to a question about Jews; not Juda**ism**. These may be interesting, but are not necessarily on topic.

Comment: Customs vary to great degree. Some things MUST be done (such as signing the ketubah, sheva brachot, etc.) and there are too many other embellishments that I have seen at weddings that I'm beginning to wonder what people are thinking, sometimes. Flower girls, best "boy", ring carriers, etc. Even the person who wheels 95 year old grandma down the aisle is considered a "kibud". Maybe narrow down the focus in your question, somewhat?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list based off of personal experience from attending Orhodox weddings. I'm making this a "community wiki" post, so it's easier for others to add to (and, incidentally, so I get no points from votes on it).

---

- *m'sader kidushin*, the (usually) rabbi who runs all the halachically relevant aspects of the wedding and says the *kidushin* blessing
- witnesses

  - to *kidushin*
  - to *nisuin* (*yichud*, and in some cases *bedekin* as well)
  - on the *k'suba*
  - on the *t'naim*, if any
- *kohen* to bless the couple
- someone to speak about the couple under the *chupa*
- someone to say the *sheva b'rachos* at the *chupa*
- someone to lead *birkas hamazon* and the *sheva b'rachos* after the meal
- someone to read the *k'suba* (and/or *t'naim*, if any)
- someone to walk the person getting married to the *chupa*, if the parent is unable
- people to walk to the *chupa* or stand under/near it

If needed there can be room to split up certain jobs (such as reciting the various *sheva b'rachos*, the various readings, and even using more than two witnesses at a particular point). You should speak with your rabbi if you seriously need more spots.

Comment: Oh, oops. The question requested them in order.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can always add more "kibbudim" to a wedding which are not necessarily part of the relatively standard and expected minhagim (thus can produce delays and frustration of wedding attendees - it's part of the chosson/kallah's hachnasas orchim to consider the guests at their first meal together) [this](https://www.yutorah.org/_cdn/_materials/Accompanying_outline_for_Shiur-517957.pdf) list does a great job outlining and detailing the kibbudim.

[image]

Comment: Note you can also always add less than this list, which currently utilizes various leniencies to add extra spots/delays. Some people mistakenly believe More is Better when it comes to this sort of thing.

Comment: I like the "in case of late/absent." Also, some chupahs need people holding them up -- a nice honor you can give to friends or relatives who aren't so comfortable with Hebrew.